# Creating multiple box plots on the same axis with data of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

What is the best approach to plotting multiple box plots on the same axis with data points of different length?

Comment: Can you add the exact function calls you're using to create the boxplots? Preferrable also add the `import`s of the libraries, and some dummy random data for your dataframe.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the info. I'm working mostly with matplotlib, seaborn, numpy but open to working with different packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Box plots](http://[1]:%20https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seab) compare distribution in a category, I would plot them monthly. Or id you mean box plot for every year side by side?

Data

```
data={'yield':[13.2 ,  4.4 ,  4.1 ,  5.1 ,  3.6 ,  7.6 ,  5.  ,  7.9 ,  4.  ,
        3.25,  4.7 ,  4.9 ,  5.5 ,  8.6 ,  7.6 ,  5.  ,  7.9 ,  4.  ,
        3.25], 'date':['13/06/2017', '20/05/2017', '23/05/2017', '23/05/2017',
       '17/06/2017', '25/06/2018', '22/06/2018', '21/06/2018',
       '21/06/2018', '22/05/2018', '20/02/2019', '23/05/2019',
       '23/05/2019', '17/03/2019', '25/06/2017', '22/07/2019',
       '23/06/2018', '2018-06-21', '22/05/2018']}
```

Set date to datetime and extract Month using [datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df['Month']=df.index.month
```

Plot box plot for each month all years combined

```
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(x="Month", y="yield", data=df)
```

If you wanted year side by side. Please add a nother column, year;

```
df['Year']=df.index.year
```

Then plot

```
y = sns.catplot(x="Month", y="yield",
                col="Year",
                data=df, kind="box")
```

Comment: You probably meant to add something like `df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month_name()`

Comment: Missed df['Month']=df.index.month while copy pasting, thanks. Now edited

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!